# chrome.webRequest is undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge-extension

Not sure where I'm going wrong here:

content.js

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(info) {
    console.log("URL intercepted: " + info.url);
  },
  // filters
  {
    urls: [
      "<all_urls>"
    ]
  },
  // extraInfoSpec
  ["blocking"]
);
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Color Changer",
  "author": "Microsoft Edge Extension Developer",
  "description": "Change the color of the body on learn.microsoft.com",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons": {
    "25": "images/color-changer25.png",
    "48": "images/color-changer48.png"
  },
    "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
        "tabs",
        "notifications",
        "http://*/",
        "https://*/"
    ], 
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "20": "images/color-changer20.png",
      "40": "images/color-changer40.png"
    },
    "default_title": "Color Changer",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "js": [
      "js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js",
      "js/content.js"
    ],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "css/*.css",
    "js/*.js",
    "html/*.html"
  ]
}
```

Error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onBeforeRequest' of undefined

Comment: Content scripts can't use most of chrome API. Do it in the background script.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm - feel free to post as answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Content scripts have some limitations. They cannot use chrome.* APIs, with the exception of extension, i18n, runtime, and storage. Instead, you need to use a background script.

Comment: do you have a working example? or may be update accepted answer with relevant code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Content scripts operate within the context of the page they are injected into. `chrome.*` isn't available to pages.